# Homology of surface of genus $g$

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is a homework question given to me by someone of the community here and it's a generalisation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41284/homology-groups-of-torus). I was wondering if you could have a look and tell me if it's right. Thanks for your help!

Task: Compute the homology of a surface of genus $g$, $\Sigma_g$.

My calculations:

(i) The cell decomposition:

- $1$ two-cell $e^2$ (a $4g$-gon)
- $2g$ one-cells $e^1_i$
- $1$ zero-cell $e^0$

(ii) The attaching map of $e^2$:

- $f_2 = a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1} \dots
     a_gb_ga_g^{-1}b_g^{-1}$

  The attaching map of $e^1$:
- $f_1 = e^0$

(iii) The chain groups:

- $C_0(\Sigma_g) = \mathbb{Z}$
- $C_1(\Sigma_g) = \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$
- $C_2(\Sigma_g) = \mathbb{Z}$
- $C_k(\Sigma_g) = 0$, $k>2$

(iv) The boundary homomorphisms:

$\dots \xrightarrow{d_3} C_2(\Sigma_g) \xrightarrow{d_2} C_1(\Sigma_g) \xrightarrow{d_1} C_0(\Sigma_g) \xrightarrow{d_0} 0$

- $d_0 = 0$
- $d_1 = 0$, because $f_1$ has degree
  $0$
- $d_2(e^2) = 0$, because each
  coefficient is $0$

(v) The homology groups:

- $H_0(\Sigma_g) = ker d_0 / im d_1 =
     \mathbb{Z} / 0 = \mathbb{Z}$
- $H_1(\Sigma_g) = ker d_1 / im d_2 =
     \mathbb{Z}^{2g} / 0 = \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$
- $H_2(\Sigma_g) = ker d_2 / im d_3 =
     \mathbb{Z} / 0 = \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: You say you're using $g$ one-cells, but your attaching map for $e^2$ involves $2g$ of them.

Comment: There is something wrong. Thank you!

Comment: It's a $4g$-gon, not a $2g$-gon! Thanks!!

Comment: Ok, maybe someone could write something as an answer, then I can accept it and this question is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the genus $g$-surface by doing the connected sum of $g$ tori $T=S^1 \times S^1$, i.e.,

$$S_g := T\,\#\,T\,\#\,\cdots\,\#\,T \qquad  (g\text{ times}).$$

Assuming you're working over $ \mathbb{Z}$.

If you know the homology of $T$, and how to find that of the connected sum, done.

If not, or if you prefer a different approach, you can:
i) Find the homology of $S^1$, then
ii) Find the homology of the product $S^1\times S^1$, and 
iii) Find the homology of the connected sum of $g$ copies in ii):

1. $H_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$
2. How to find the homology of a product space, (e.g., Künneth's formula)
    it is $\mathbb{Z}^2$
3. Finding the homology of connected sums; it is the direct sum of the respective
    homologies; the basis curves are pairwise disjoint, so the homology is the
    direct sum (what happens in one Torus, stays in that Torus)
    You ultimately get: $$H_1(S_g)=\mathbb{Z}^{2g}$$ you are done.

Comment: I don't know if this is the approach you wanted, but I think it may give you a kind of quick-and-dirty way of getting the homology without having to do the whole thing ground-up all the time (tho it is a good idea to do ground-up a few times)

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting and TeX. Note: the sign $\times$ is obtained by using `\times`. If you want more than one letter as superscript use curly braces: $\mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ is obtained by `\mathbb{Z}^{2g}`. You can see what I did by clicking on the 'edited xx time' ago over my name.

Comment: Nice, thanks. What are the basis curves?

Comment: PS: I'm doing ground-up to practice ; )

Comment: @Matt: they are a meridian and a parallel; two representatives of non-trivial cycles that do not bound. The class (m,n) then goes m times around a meridian and n times around a parallel.

Comment: Theo: thanks, I am still working on it.

Comment: @gary: Okay, I see. By the way: add an `@`-sign in front of your comments, then the corresponding user gets notified.

Comment: @Matt, another comment: the choice of the two curves has to see with the fact that if we were to cut or remove the curves, the remaining space would be connected; in that sense, they do not bound, so they are non-trivial curves. Hope this is not too trivial of a comment; it helped me when I learnt about it.

Comment: @Theo: I meant to say that I am still working on learning how to do the formatting correctly; thanks for your patience!

Comment: @gary: Thanks. Explanations can never be too trivial ; )

Comment: @gary: I reincorporated my changes. I hope they're fine with you. To learn LaTeX I found Tobi Oetiker's *[Not so short introduction to LaTeX](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/)* invaluable (download lshort.pdf there). To learn the syntax for markdown formatting here, [here's more than you need to know](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics).

Comment: So what's the reason for the downvote?