# Homology of a torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to compute the homology of a torus by its chain map, *rather than* its equivalence to $\oplus H_n (S^1)$.

The post [Homology groups of torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41284/homology-groups-of-torus)
has been really helpful, but my question is, how can I come up with the boundary maps, so that I could use $H_n = \frac{\ker \partial_n}{\operatorname{Im} \partial_{n+1}}$?

Comment: The boundary map in the post you linked use cell homology. Did you learn how the boundary map is defined in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The torus can be seen as

[image: torus]

with the left and right edges identified and the top and bottom edges identified, using the notation in the question linked to.

From this, you can compute the boundary maps: $\delta_2(e^2) = e^1_a + e^1_b - e^1_a - e^1_b = 0$, $\delta_1(e^1_a) = e^0 - e^0 = 0$, and $\delta_1(e^1_b) = e^0 - e^0 = 0$.

Comment: That makes so much sense! It's so clear!! Thank you Magdiragdag!